# Can I connect TV internal Speakers to 3.5mm plug?

Tags: speakers, rca

I had 48" broken TV with good speakers. I removed them from mainboard where each comes with 2 pins. Can I connect them to RCA male and then connect to 3.5mm to RCA adapter where I can use it for computer or laptop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course you can. But why involve any RCA connectors? Just get a 3.5 mm TRS (tip-ring-sleeve, 3 conductors) and wire it up directly.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1KwiZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: You won't get much volume out of the speakers if you connect it directly to the PC line out/headphone out.

Comment: @hatsunearu: That's a separate question. First, we need to get the OP hooked up, and then let him decide whether it's loud enough. Computers definitely ARE capable of driving reasonably efficient speakers directly.

Comment: :| quite the different philosophy you got there... I'd prefer if people warn me instead of giving a thumbs up if i'm about to shoot myself in the foot

Comment: @hatsunearu: No shooting here. Nothing will get damaged by trying this out.

Comment: Ehhh, but OP would waste their time soldering.

Comment: @hatsunearu: Not at all. Even if he ends up needing an amplifier, the speakers still need a plug to connect to it!

Comment: @hatsunearu you yourself recommended an LM386 – that's got 325 mW max output power. My PC motherboard's soundcard can actually drive more.

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to connect raw speakers to a computer, you can't do that. The speakers require a lot more power than what can come out of a computer. The computer can put out enough power for a pair of headphones, which you can only hear if you place your ears right next to it. If you tried what you wrote in the OP, you won't get much volume out of the speakers, and you also risk breaking your computer audio output.

You should get yourself an audio amplifier. You can get one at a store, or you can make your own. There are plenty of tutorials online to make the latter. Here's one I particularly like: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3dQjIeYoIdM

Comment: ... if you actually want acceptable audio quality out of speakers, please use something better than the antique LM386. So many nicer ICs exist!

Comment: Yeah... I suggest my first option of buying whatever is on amazon, haha. If I were to do it today I'd go with a much fancier setup... and a better speaker...

Comment: yeah, if you want to use your TV speakers because they are *nice*, you wouldn't want to drive them with an LM386 – it has 300 mW of output power, and certainly that certainly won't do much good when driving 2, 4, or 8Ω speakers. It's really the wrong choice.

Comment: OK I removed all references to the LM386. May it rest in peace.

Comment: Not really. Your video shows using an LM386 as a preamp(!) for the class-D power amp.

Comment: lol, it's been a while since I saw that video. That sounds alright in my book though. Well... it might not *sound* alright.